# Converting Integers to Binary in Ruby

Tags: ruby, binary, integer

I'm working on a codewars kata and stuck with 2 test cases that are failing.

The kata description is:
Convert integers to binary as simple as that. You would be given an integer as a argument and you have to return its binary form. To get an idea about how to convert a decimal number into a binary number, visit here.

Notes: negative numbers should be handled as two's complement; assume all numbers are integers stored using 4 bytes (or 32 bits) in any language.

My code:

```
def to_binary(n)
  temp_array = []
  if n == 0
    temp_array << 0
  elsif n < 0
    n = n % 256
    while n > 0 do
      temp_array << (n % 2)
      n = (n / 2)
    end
    while temp_array.length < 32 do
      temp_array << 1
    end
  else
    while n > 0 do
      temp_array << (n % 2)
      n = (n / 2)
    end
  end
  binary = temp_array.reverse.join
end
```

The test cases are:

```
Test Passed: Value == "10"
Test Passed: Value == "11"
Test Passed: Value == "100"
Test Passed: Value == "101"
Test Passed: Value == "111"
Test Passed: Value == "1010"
Test Passed: Value == "11111111111111111111111111111101"
Test Passed: Value == "0"
Test Passed: Value == "1111101000"
Test Passed: Value == "11111111111111111111111111110001"
Expected: "11111111111111111111110000011000", instead got: "11111111111111111111111111111000"
Expected: "11111111111100001011110111000001", instead got: "11111111111111111111111111000001"
Test Passed: Value == "11110100001000111111"
```

I suspect the tests that are failing are with negative integers because the first failing test's expected output is `11111111111111111111110000011000` which means that either the positive argument value was `4294966296` or it was negative.  If I run `to_binary(4294966296)` I get the expected output.

Comment: I assume you want to write the algorithm, even though ruby has a built-in conversion `10.to_s(2) => "1010"'

Comment: @500_error except that `(-10).to_s(2) => "-1010"`

Comment: @lurker Considering negative binary values don't really exist, that's a reasonable interpretation. A common notation for representing these is [Two's Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) but that's hardly the only way to do it.

Comment: @tadman sure, but I'm saying it doesn't solve the OP's problem looking for a 32-bit 2's complement result.

Comment: Ah just saw that part. Nothing you can't fix with some manipulation to offset the value prior to `to_s(2)`.

Comment: @lurker `[-10].pack('L').unpack('L')[0].to_s(2)` will give the right representation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not fond of this approach since I'm sure there's an even more clever and/or compact, Ruby-esque way of accomplishing it. But using your method of loading binary digits into an array, and then joining, what you have can be done in a little more straight-forward fashion:

```
def to_binary(n)
  return "0" if n == 0

  r = []

  32.times do
    if (n & (1 << 31)) != 0
      r << 1
    else
      (r << 0) if r.size > 0
    end
    n <<= 1
  end

  r.join
end
```

Or, using @500_error's suggestion:

```
def to_binary(n)
  if n >= 0
    n.to_s(2)
  else
    31.downto(0).map { |b| n[b] }.join
  end
end
```

The asymmetry to deal with negative versus non-negative is a little annoying, though. You could do something like:

```
def to_binary(n)
  31.downto(0).map { |b| n[b] }.join.sub(/^0*/, "")
end
```

Comment: there is a clever approach http://calleerlandsson.com/2014/02/06/rubys-bitwise-operators/

Comment: 32.downto(0).map { |n| -4294966296[n] }.join
=> "100000000000000000000001111101000"

Comment: @500_error yes, that's quite nice. The only remaining issue is that, for example, `32.downto(0).map { |n| 2[n] }.join => "00000000000000000000000000000010"` but the OP expects "10".

Comment: Ya, It's clever, but not sure if it is a good answer for OP's use case. There should be some bit shifting so the conversion is understood.

Comment: Thank you @lurker and @500_error, this worked with one minor change: 

```ruby
def to_binary(n)
  if n >= 0
    n.to_s(2)
  else
    31.downto(0).map { |b| n[b] }.join
  end
end
```

The original method was allowing the method to return up to 33 bits instead of 32.  This method is also way shorter than what I had.  I'm still new to ruby and will be dissecting this method to better understand it. :) Thank you!

Comment: @OggimusPrime thanks for catching that. As they say in the software biz "You're always off by 1". :) I'll fix the answer so as not to mislead other readers.

Comment: @lurker so true on the off by 1.  Thank you again :)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a traditional algorithm to generate 2's complement, so I am not sure if it helps you in understanding binary conversion, but you can do this in ruby to help check your answers.

Note: This applies to negative number's only.

```
32.downto(0).map { |n| -4294966296[n] }.join
=> "100000000000000000000001111101000"
```

For 2's complement computation, it's best to implement using a lower level language like C, to get a sense of the algorithm. The clever approaches mask the steps and just give you an answer.

Suppose we're working with 8 bits (for simplicity's sake) and suppose we want to find how -28 would be expressed in two's complement notation.

1. First we write out 28 in binary form.
   00011100
2. Then we invert the digits. 0 becomes 1, 1 becomes 0.
   11100011
3. Then we add 1.
   11100100

Comment: +1 for that nice expression. `32.downto(0).map { |n| 2[n] }.join => "00000000000000000000000000000010"` yields `""00000000000000000000000000000010"` instead of `"10"`. Perhaps there's a minor mod to this nice approach that fixes it.

Comment: @lurker you could just convert to an integer to squash leading zeros...`x = 2; 32.downto(0).map { |n| x[n] }.join.to_i`  and if you insist on the result being a string, just convert it back `x = 2; 32.downto(0).map { |n| x[n] }.join.to_i.to_s`

Comment: @SteveTurczyn yep, absolutely right. I'm assuming the OP required a string output (since they wanted the output as a "binary" representation).